# How to exit a programm with an error message and error code in bash?

Tags: bash, error-handling

I'd like to exit a script when an operation could not be executed.

```
non-existing || exit 1;
```

works fine and exits, while

```
ls || exit 1;
```

does not exit. Now, I'd also like to add an error message before exiting the program.

```
non-existing || echo "Having trouble" && exit 1;
```

exits as expected, but

```
ls || echo "Having trouble" && exit 1;
```

also exits, although the `echo` command (and thus the `exit`) should not be executed.

I first thought that using brackets might help:

```
ls || (echo "Having trouble" && exit 1;)
```

Does not exit. But when I invoke a non-existing program, the `exit`-command only exits from the sub-shell that I opened using the brackets:

```
non-existing || (echo "Having trouble" && exit 1;)
echo "Still executed."
```

- **How can I exit a program with an error message in bash?**
- Why does `ls || echo "Having trouble" && exit 1;` exit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Use `{ ...; }` instead of `(...)` to avoid the sub-shell and the problem that causes and to get the result that you want.

Note that a space after the opening `{` and a semicolon/etc. and a space before the closing `}` are *required* for this (where they are optional with `()`).

As to why `ls || echo && exit` doesn't do what you expect the answer is because the `||` and `&&` operators have the same precedence and are left-associative (see the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03)).

So when the shell sees

```
ls || echo "Having trouble" && exit 1;
```

you think it is

```
ls || { echo "Having trouble" && exit 1; }
```

but the shell parses it as

```
{ ls || echo "Having trouble"; } && exit 1;
```

Or, as the spec puts it:

> The operators "&&" and "||" shall have equal precedence and shall be evaluated with left associativity. For example, both of the following commands write solely bar to standard output:
>
> false && echo foo || echo bar
>
> true || echo foo && echo bar

Comment: Also note that `A && B || C` will execute C if **either** A **or** B exit unsuccessfully, as opposed to `if A; then B; else C; fi` which executes C only if A exits unsuccessfully.

Comment: Indeed, which is why shellcheck has warning [SC2015](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2015).